# Generate XML from database table

Tags: xml, t-sql, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I have a table without any type of hierarchy that needs to be output in XML, then formatted and ordered based on numbers in the `SEQ` column. I'm using ColdFusion to generate the XML since the formatting output is a bit complex for TSQL to handle. My problem is that I'm a little lost as to how to properly have ColdFusion handle IDs where there may be more than the number of rows I have in my template file.

Here is general idea of what I'm working with:

My table for only 1 ID (I'd want this for thousands of IDs):

```
MODNM | CARNM | PARTID   | PARNAME  | SEQ | TYPE | VALUE                     | FLAG
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
M-880 | HONA  | 29000153 | SETGROUP | 1   | A    | 3                         | P
M-880 | HONA  | 29000153 | *CDMZI   | 2   | A    | F%+A8E=,,,0;+MS=V123,456; | P
M-880 | HONA  | 29000153 | DMTZ     | 3   | A    |                           | P
M-880 | HONA  | 29000153 | CDRFCP   | 4   | A    | 0                         | P
M-880 | HONA  | 29000153 | SETGROUP | 5   | A    | 15                        | P
M-880 | HONA  | 29000153 | #PT      | 5   | 6    | NONE                      | P
M-880 | HONA  | 29000153 | CDH6     | 7   | A    | 100.111.100.44            | P
M-880 | HONA  | 29000153 | CDEPORT  | 8   | A    | 9003                      | P
```

XML format needs to be:

```
<Device PartID="29000153" MODNM="M-880">
  <Car Name="HONA">
    <Group GID="3">
      <Pmeter ParName="*CDMZI" Value="F%+A8E=,,,0;+MS=V123,456;" Type="A" Flag="P" />
      <Pmeter ParName="DMTZ" Value="" Type="A" Flag="P" />
      <Pmeter ParName="CDRFCP" Value="0" Type="A" Flag="P" />
    </Group>
    <Group GID="15">
      <Pmeter ParName="#PT" Value="NONE" Type="A" Flag="P" />
      <Pmeter ParName="CDH6" Value="100.111.100.44" Type="A" Flag="P" />
      <Pmeter ParName="CDEPORT" Value="9003" Type="A" Flag="P" />
    </Group>
  </Car>
  <DevFiles />
</Device>
```

I have ColdFusion setup in the following manner to generate XML file. Issue is that I don't know exactly how to have ColdFusion dynamically handle IDs when there are more `PARNAMES` then what is set aside in the template file.

runXMLgen.cfm - generates XML file

1. `CFQUERY` to pull all IDs from table
2. use `<cfinclude template>` for xmltmplt.cfm
3. use `CFFILE` to store XML file into local directory

   SELECT PARTID, PARNAME, VALUE, SEQ, FLAG, TYPE
       FROM PMETER
       WHERE PARTID in ('290000153')
       AND MODNM= 'M-880'
          AND CARNM = 'HONA'
       ORDER BY SEQ ASC

   ```
   <cfset xmlStartData = "<SData>#chr(13)##chr(10)##chr(32)##chr(32)#<Devices SpecVersion=""1.0"">#chr(13)##chr(10)#" />
   <cffile action="append" addnewline="no" file="C:\extract.xml" output="#xmlStartData#" />
     <Devices SpecVersion="1.0">   
   <cfoutput>
       <cfloop query="bextract">
           <cfinclude template="xmltmplt.cfm" />
           <cffile action="append" addnewline="no" file="C:\extract.xml" output="#bParams#" />
       </cfloop>
   </cfoutput>
     </Devices>
   <cfset xmlEndData = "#chr(32)##chr(32)#</Devices>#chr(13)##chr(10)#</SData>" />
   <cffile action="append" addnewline="no" file="C:\extract.xml" output="#xmlEndData#" />
   ```

xmltmplt.cfm - hardcoded template which is supposed to automatically generate the values based on seq order, and start new  when it sees setgroup as the parname. Below is somewhat incomplete as I am not escaping values, but this is basically where I'm stuck at. Figuring out how to dynamically populate XML file based on seqorder and certain parnames without knowing how many parnames an ID may have.

```
<cfset bParams = " <Device PartID="#partID#" MODNM="#modnm">#chr13#
 <Car Name="#carnm#">#chr13#
  <Group GID="#parname#">#chr13#
   <Pmeter ParName="#parname#" Value="#value#" Type="#type#" Flag="#flag#" />#chr13#
   <Pmeter ParName="#parname#" Value="#value#" Type="#type#" Flag="#flag#" />#chr13#
  </Group>#chr13#
  <Group GID="#parname#">#chr13#
   <Pmeter ParName="#parname#" Value="#value#" Type="#type#" Flag="#flag#" />#chr13#
   <Pmeter ParName="#parname#" Value="#value#" Type="#type#" Flag="#flag#" />#chr13#
  </Group>#chr13#
 </Car>#chr13#
 <DevFiles />#chr13#
</Device> " />
```

Comment: You need to post the code showing how you generate the current xml. It sounds like it is hard coded somehow. Have you tried using cfoutput group=".."? It would require several "groups", but if structured correctly, you could use it to generate an unknown number of PARNAMES elements.

Comment: Having serious nubtacular issues posting the code with stackoverflow's formatting. Even with the 4 spaces indented, my code gets stripped out when I go to post. Any ideas?

Comment: Silly question. Are you sure it is not just being treated as text? That could cause cfml to "disappear" because browser sees it as html tags, so it is not displayed. Also, did you try the code button ie `{}`.

Comment: Have everything up now updated on my post. The xmltmplt.cfm file is incomplete, but it should give an idea of what I am doing right now and looking for suggestions or solutions as to how to do this better since certain IDs could have unknown number of groups and parnames.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could probably abuse `<cfoutput group="...">` and use it to generate the required nesting. It would require a small tweak to your query in order to generate the proper GID groupings. This may not be exact, but should get you started. (Note: I deliberately omitted `XmlFormat` for brevity, but do use it in your actual code).

**NB:** *When using "group", the query result MUST be sorted in the exact same order as your groupings or it will not work properly*

```
<cfquery name="getParts" ....>
   SELECT PARTID
          , MODNUM
          , CARNM
          , ParName
          , VALUE
          , TYPE
          , FLAG
          , CASE WHEN PARNAME = 'SETGROUP' THEN 1 ELSE 0  END AS IsGroupHeader
   FROM   YourTable 
   ORDER BY PARTID
         , CARNM
         , SEQ
         , IsGroupHeader
</cfquery>


<cfsavecontent variable="content"> 
<cfoutput query="getParts" group="PARTID">
<Device PartID="#PARTID#" MODNM="#MODNUM#">
   <cfoutput group="CARNM">
      <Car Name="#CARNM#">
      <cfoutput group="IsGroupHeader">
        <!-- If this is the SETGROUP value, generate opening tag --->   
        <cfif IsGroupHeader>
            <Group GID="#VALUE#">
        <cfelse>
            <cfoutput>
             <Pmeter ParName="#PARNAME#" Value="#VALUE#" Type="#TYPE#" Flag="#FLAG#" />
            </cfoutput>
         </Group>
        </cfif>
     </cfoutput>
     </Car>
   </cfoutput>
</Device></cfoutput>
</cfsavecontent>

<cfdump var="#content#" label="Show generated XML">
```

Comment: Thanks Leigh, I'll give this a try today and update on result.

Comment: On second thought, that doesn't quite do the trick. See my updated response.

Comment: The value for #PARNAME# doesn't actually come up, instead boolean value shows up "0". How can I get the actual value for parname to come up?

Comment: (Edit) Works fine for me. It generates `ParName="*CDMZI"`, etcetera. Maybe your query differs from mine? Did you include that column in your SELECT list? See my updated query above.

Comment: Ok, that did it. I don't understand, I did the same thing but had it in a different order in the SELECT statement. Is that why I had an issue?

Comment: (Edit) The SELECT list order should not matter, but the `ORDER BY` clause does. How the query results are sorted is very significant when using a grouped output. The query results must be sorted *exactly* the same way you are grouping. If the two differ, it will not work properly.